# Key variety technique, a history question

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ho.history-overview

I have a history question about the technique called "key variety technique" used in algebraic geometry. (see eg http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.9.6880). One can find many papers that use this technique. Can some one tell me who introduced this technique and the paper in which it was used for the first time?

Thanks